# get unknown filename to zip the file in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

I am looking for a way to zip a file with an unknown filename. i am struggling on how to get the filename into  my variable.
this my code:

```
set HOST=%1
set DRIVELTR=%2
set OMGEVING=%3

FOR %%i IN (\\%HOST%\%DRIVELTR%$\%OMGEVING%\*.*) DO set filename="%%~i"

"C:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -r -sdel  \\%HOST%\%DRIVELTR%$\%OMGEVING%\filename.zip \\%HOST%\%DRIVELTR%$\%OMGEVING%\filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
FOR %%i IN ("\\%~1\%~2$\%~3\*.*") DO (
    "C:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -r -sdel  "%%~dpni.zip" "%%~fi"
)
```

Where

- `%~1` to `%~3` are the arguments to the batch file without quotes
- `%%~dpni` is the drive, path and name (without extension) of the file being referenced by `%%i`
- `%%~fi` is the full path of the file being referenced by `%%i`

NOTE: As the `.zip` files are being generated in the same folder that is being iterated, it is possible that the `for` loop retrieves the new `.zip` files. If you can not narrow the wildcard or generate the `.zip` files elsewhere, you can check if the file extension is `.zip` before trying to compress the file

```dos
FOR %%i IN ("\\%~1\%~2$\%~3\*.*") DO if /i not "%%~xi"==".zip" (
    "C:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -r -sdel  "%%~dpni.zip" "%%~fi"
)
```

Comment: Tank you for the quick response. i will try it later on.